# R: elegant way to determine numeric variables in a data frame

Tags: r, vectorization

Here's the code I use to find numeric variables in a data frame:

```
Data <- iris
numericvars <- NULL
for (Var in names(Data)) {
    if(class(Data[,Var]) == 'integer' | class(Data[,Var]) == 'numeric') {
        numericvars <- c(numericvars,Var)
    }
}
numericvars
```

Is there a less loopy way to do this?

Comment: Growing objects in a loop is a no-no (`numericvars <- c(numericvars,Var)`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a pretty simple one-liner with `sapply`:

```
sapply(Data, is.numeric)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE        FALSE

# is.numeric should pick up integer columns too
Data$Species <- as.integer(Data$Species)
sapply(Data, is.numeric)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE
```

Comment: Species comes out TRUE in the second attempt.

Comment: @Dirk: ...as it should, according to `?is.numeric`.

Comment: Asleep at the wheel here -- I missed that you transformed the factor to integer.

Comment: Eyes on the puck, or eyes on the player?

Comment: Same as football; eyes on the player's lower body.

Comment: Using vapply is a little more robust. Doesn't matter here but is good practice when writing functions.

Answer (score 5):

This is a little tighter:

```
R> sapply(colnames(iris), function(x) inherits(iris[,x], c("numeric","integer")))
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE        FALSE 
R>
```

Comment: Ooops.  Guess I was a few moments too late.

Comment: Is there any reason to `sapply` over column names and not by `data.frame` itself? `sapply(iris, inherits, c("numeric", "integer"))`

Answer (score 3):

The use of `sapply()` or `lapply()` seems logical here:

```
sapply(iris, function(x) class(x) %in% c("integer","numeric"))
```

which gives:

```
> sapply(iris, function(x) class(x) %in% c("integer","numeric"))
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE        FALSE
```

Worth noting that in your loop, you are growing the `numericvars` vector at each iteration of the loop; in R, that is a big no-no! It forces R to copy and expand the vector each time. Allocate sufficient storage before hand and fill in the object; here that would mean creating `numericvars` as

```
numericvars <- character(length = ncol(iris))
```

then in the loop doing

```
nams <- names(iris)
for(i in seq_len(ncol(iris))) {
    if(class(iris[, i]) == 'integer' | class(iris[, i]) == 'numeric') {
        numericvars[i] <- nams[i]
    }
}
```

A little bit more work, but far more efficient, though you'll only see it when the number of iterations becomes larger.

Answer (score 3):

There's also `colwise()`, `numcolwise()` and `catcolwise()` in plyr. `colwise()` turns a function that operates on a vector into a function that works column-wise on a dataframe. `numcolwise` and `catcolwise` provide versions that operate only on numeric and discrete variables respectively.

```
library(plyr)
colwise(is.numeric)(Data)

> colwise(is.numeric)(Data)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1         TRUE        TRUE         TRUE        TRUE   FALSE
```